# XPATH OR operator does not see

Tags: xpath

I am trying to use the OR operator where I want either expression to work.

The expression work individual but not together can you help please see below

```
//*[[@class='eline'][1]/following-sibling::tr] OR [[@class='eline'][1]]
```

Hi,

Here is a better example for you below so I am happy with your first solution as this selected everything but then I wanted to select the element where alt="Ab" as this elements position may change so I want the xpath to be a dynamic as possible

```
<tr class="eline">
<tr>
<td class="norm" nowrap=""/>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">
<td class="norm" nowrap="">
<td class="norm" nowrap="">cccc cccc </td>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">99999 </td>
<td class="norm" nowrap=""/>
<td>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">
<img width="20" vspace="0" border="0" hspace="0" height="15" alt="Ab" name="abs3" src="images/sp_abs.gif"/>
</td>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">
<td class="norm" nowrap="">testcase33 testcase33 </td>
<td class="norm" nowrap="">33100 </td>
<td class="norm" nowrap=""/>
<td class="norm" nowrap=""/>
</tr>
<tr class="eline">
<tr>
<tr class="eline">
<tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid XPath to me.  Can you edit the question to include some sample XML and explain exactly which nodes you want to select?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are attempting to select:

- the first element with the `class` attribute `eline`
- all following sibling `tr` elements

The simplest way is simply to combine the two selectors that did work using the union `|` operator:

```
//*[@class='eline'][1]/following-sibling::tr | //*[@class='eline'][1]
```

For instance, with this XML:

```
<table>
    <tr name="first"/>
    <tr class="eline" />
    <tr name="third"/>
    <tr name="fourth"/>
</table>
```

the above XPath would give

```
<tr class="eline"/>
<tr name="third"/>
<tr name="fourth"/>
```

---

Presuming you want to find an element `img[@alt="Ab"]` from within the elements selected by the code above, you can do it with something like this:

```
(//*[@class='eline'][1]/following-sibling::tr | //*[@class='eline'][1]) // img[@alt="Ab"]
```

Comment: Wow that is perfect, thanks so much, why I never heard this is beyond me but again you got it all in one-- nice start to my Monday

Comment: Hi, I need to now select a certain attribute within this selection , how is this done. Here is what I have tried //*[@class='eline'][1]/following-sibling::tr | //*[@class='eline'][1] AND [@alt="Ab"]

Comment: @user1156718 Something like `(//*[@class='eline'][1]/following-sibling::tr | //*[@class='eline'][1])[@alt="Ab"]`

Comment: Hi,this did not find the element and other idea's or am I going about it wrong way, select everything first and then filter as it can change but will always be withtin the bounds of //*[@class='eline'][1]/following-sibling::tr | //*[@class='eline'][1]

Comment: @user1156718 It is very hard to work on XPath when you can't see the XML you're working on! Perhaps you could edit your question with (a) what you already have and (b) what you want to find.

Comment: sorry my fault i have edited they question now with more detail, let me know if this makes it clear